# "Cannot update: Duplicate entry '*username*' for key 1"

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

So im trying to have a user update their profile from update.php and then display it in userprofile.php but I am getting the error :"Cannot update: Duplicate entry '*username*' for key 1". Ive tried to find a solution but im pretty stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is update.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

 <title>User Profile Update</title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

</head>

<body>


<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE)
{
$userError = "Error! Invalid Username.";
$passError = "Error! Invalid Password.";
$emailError = "Error! Invalid Email.";
$conError = "Error! Passwords do not match.";

$errorCheck = false;

$regex = '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD';




if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
if(empty($_POST["firstName"])){
echo $userError;
$errorCheck = True;
}
elseif(empty($_POST["lastName"])){
echo $passError;
$errorCheck = True;
}
elseif(empty($_POST["userName"])){
echo $userError;
$errorCheck = True;
}
elseif(empty($_POST["pass"])){
echo $passError;
$errorCheck = True;
}
elseif(preg_match($regex, $_POST["email"]) != 1) {
echo $emailError;
$errorCheck = True;
} 
elseif($_POST["pass"] != $_POST["pass2"]){
echo $conError;
$errorCheck = True;
}
elseif($_POST["address"] != $_POST["address"]){
echo $conError;
$errorCheck = True;
}   

if(isset($_POST['update']) && (!$errorCheck)){  
$user="bparis";
$pass="soccerguy998";
$database="bparis";

$passwordSub=$_POST["pass"]; 
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($passwordSub);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pass)
or die ('Couldnt connect to server');
mysql_select_db($database,$con)
or die('could not connect to db');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$key_id = $_POST["userName"];

$key_id2 = $_POST["email"];

//$location = $_POST['location'];
update($key_id2);
}else
{

userupdate();}  
}else
{userupdate();}

}else  
{    //if no user is logged in, display error   

echo "<h1>Access denied</h1>";
echo "<h3><a href=login.php>Click here to login</a></h3>";

} 
?>


<?php
function update($email){
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

$sQry = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = " . (int)$_SESSION['email']; // Int userid
$obQry = mysql_query($sQry) or die(mysql_error()); // Shortcut, bad but usable
if (mysql_num_rows($obQry) == 1)
{
// Single record exists:// EDIT USER_PROFILE
$sReplace = "UPDATE members (username,password,email,firstName,lastName,address) VALUES('$_POST[userName]','$encrypted_mypassword','$_POST[email]','$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[address]')";

// Remember, I assumed that email is an integer!
}
else
{
$passwordSub=$_POST["pass"]; 
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($passwordSub);
$sReplace = "INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,firstName,lastName,address) VALUES('$_POST[userName]','$encrypted_mypassword','$_POST[email]','$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[address]')";

}

$obUpdate = mysql_query($sReplace) or die('Cannot update: ' . mysql_error());
if($obUpdate){
$subject = "Profile updated ";
$message = "You have updated your profile with Belfort Furniture. If not please contact customer service at : 703-406-7600";
$Belfortemail = "akomala.akouete@belfortfurniture.com";
echo "<b>profile updated</b>";mail($email, $subject,$message, "From:" . $Belfortemail);}else{
echo "Try update again";}
}
?>
<?php   
function userupdate(){
?>

<table>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<h1>Profile Update</h1>
<hr>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td>

<input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="20">

</td></tr>

<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td>

<input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="20">

</td></tr>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td>

<input type="text" name="userName" maxlength="20">

</td></tr>

<tr><td>Password:</td><td>

<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="20">

</td></tr>

<tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td>

<input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="20">

</td></tr>

<tr><td>Email:</td><td>

<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50">

</td></tr>

<tr><td>Address:</td><td>

<input type="text" name="address" maxlength="100">

</td></tr>
<!--<tr>
                           <td class="right">address 1: </td>
                           <td><input type="text" name="location" value="" size="60" /></td>
                       </tr>-->


<tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE"></th></tr>

</form>
</table>

<?php
echo "<br><h3><a href=usersProfile.php>View your profile</a></h3>";
}
?>


</body>

</html>
```

and here is userprofile.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
# DB INFO #
$user="xxxx";
$pass="xxxxx";
$database="xxxxx";


$con=mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pass)
or die ('Couldnt connect to server');
mysql_select_db($database,$con)
or die('could not connect to db');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT userName,email,firstName,lastName,address FROM members") or die(mysql_error()); 
showpUsers($result);

function showpUsers($result)
{   
?> 
<table border="1">
  <tr>  
     <?php

$headings = array("Usernam","Email","First Name","Last Name","Address"); 
      foreach($headings as $info) {
        echo "<th border='1'>" . $info . "</th>";
     }

     ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
  if(count($result)>0){

$list = array("username","email","firstName","lastName","address"); 
//while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  $data = $result;
  echo "<tr border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
echo "<td border='1'>" . $data[$i] . "</td>";
}
 echo "</tr>";
//}

}else{
echo "<b>Empty users list</b>";
}
  ?>
</table>

<?php
}
echo "<a href=update.php><button type='button'>USER UPDATE</button> </h1>";
?>
<hr/>
<br/>
<a href="index.php"><h3>Return Home Page</h3></a>
```

Comment: In your MYSQL schema, `username` is probably the primary key, and can't be duplicated.  Probably better that you have an autoincremented integer as the primary key.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Use mysqli or PDO, and prepared statements.

Comment: most probably you may want to show the user an error message if the username is duplicate.

Comment: Side notes: You're open to SQL injection - escape your user inputs; `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated;

Comment: Your UPDATE query doesn't have a where clause(you could use the username as the key), and it's not using the proper syntax either. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two situations I can see that might cause this:

1. You have **two or more** rows in the database with the same `username`, and your `INSERT` statement is being called. Check for this explicitly by only calling this block if the number of rows returned was 0. At the moment you aren't testing for it at all.
2. Your `username` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for the table. In this case you should alter your table so that it has a unique auto_incrementing primary key.

---

Oh, and rewrite the whole thing to fix the massive SQL injection vulnerabilities. Don't let this code anywhere near a public web site in the state it's in.